# I have created custom field in Activity Task in salesforce

Tags: workflow

I have created custom field in Task whenever the Escalated checkbox field is checked the Case comments should update "This case is escalated" in salesforce. How to do that?

Comment: You can achive this with trigger

Comment: Have you looked at using [Process Builder](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/business_process_automation/process_builder)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **process builder** to achieve this.

If you don't know what is process builder or how to use it then complete this **trailhead module**
 https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/business_process_automation/process_builder